# Add title to pdf using itext

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, pdf, itext

```
{
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A3, 32, 32, 32, 32);
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
   document.open();
  HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "", "");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from test3");
   List arrlist = new ArrayList();
    while(rs.next()){
   String xa =rs.getString("display");
  if(xa.equals("1")){
  arrlist.add(rs.getString("question_text"));
  }
}
Collections.shuffle(arrlist); 
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    String str = (String) arrlist.get(i);
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader("<br>"));
}
document.close();
}
```

Above is a code snippet which gets data from the database and displays on pdf.How do I add a title, logo,date and page no.to this?Please if anyone could help.I am using itext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out some of the [page event examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204). Currently, you're creating an unnamed `PdfWriter` instance. Change this into a named writer instance and declare a page event before opening the document instance:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
writer.setPageEvent(new MyPageEvents());
```

The `MyPageEvents` class is to be written by you. It needs to implement the `PdfPageEvent` interface, or, better yet, extend the `PdfPageEventHelper` class.

Adding a title, logo, date,... in the header is done by implementing the `onEndPage()` method. **Do NOT use the `onStartPage()` method without reading the documentation!!!**

Use these [`onEndPage()` examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=220) for inspiration.

To add an Image, add a member variable `img` to your page event, and add this to your constructor:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(pathToImage);
img.setAbsolutePosition(36, 806);
```

Then in the `onEndPage()` method, do this:

```
writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);
```

This will add the image at position x = 36, y = 806 (near the left top of the page). Note that it's important that you don't create a new `Image` instance for every new page, because that would result in a bloated PDF file. By creating the `Image` in the constructor of your page event and reusing the object, the image bytes will be present only once in the PDF file.

Comment: I am done with page number and header.I need to know how to put the logo.

Comment: I'll add some extra lines to my answer.

Comment: I didnt realize who replied to me until today.Great to hear from you sir.

Comment: but one more thing if I require it for A4,A3,A2,A1 the position changes.Any solution for that?

Comment: You'll notice that `onEndPage()` receives a `Document` parameter. This isn't the same `Document` instance you're creating in your code. Instead it's an internal `PdfDocument` instance created by `PdfWriter`. You can use this object for read-only purposes, for instance to get the page size. In other words: you can calculate the coordinates based on information you can obtain with `document.getPageSize()`.

Comment: Please could you help solve another problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890856/html-to-pdf-using-itext

Comment: No, I can't, as soon as I see `HTMLWorker` I stop reading, because `HTMLWorker` has been discontinued in favor of XML Worker.