# html to pdf using itext xmlworker

Tags: pdf, xml-parsing, itext, html-to-pdf

```
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, ml, mr, mt, mb);
   PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
   String sc_na=request.getParameter("school_name");
   String name=sc_na;
   writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderAndFooter(name));
   document.open();
   XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
   //HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elect", "root", "root");
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from test3");
   List arrlist = new ArrayList();
   while(rs.next()){
   String xa =rs.getString("display");
   if(xa.equals("1")){
    arrlist.add(rs.getString("question_text"));
   }
 }
 Collections.shuffle(arrlist); 
for(int i=0;i<nb;i++){
    String str = (String) arrlist.get(i);
     worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader("<br>"));
     worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(str));

}
document.close();
```

This is a snippet of my code.Using I get all my data in one single column.What should I do so that I can  get into multiple columns.One way I guess is using PDFptable but how do I apply it here.Please Help.

Comment: HTMLWorker is deprecated and is no longer supported. It's been replaced by XMLWorker. I'm not saying it's going to solve your issue, but you are definitely more likely to get help for up-to-date libs.

Comment: i tried using xmlworker but get alot of errors so decided to go back with htmlworker.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For Html to PDF, use Flying Saucer: http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

It uses iText 2.0.8 and it respects a CSS. It is as much code as:

```
 org.w3c.dom.Document doc = . . .
 ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
 renderer.setDocument(doc, null);

 renderer.layout();
 renderer.createPDF(out);
```

Make sure your XHTML links to a reachable CSS, e.g.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file://. . ./pdf.css" media="print"/>
```